# problem on set content view

Tags: android

I have two xml file. I want this two xml file in the same activity but when I try to use it I am getting error.

code for 1.xml

```
<LinearLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
       android:background="@drawable/back_image">
      <ImageView android:src="@drawable/loading_logo"
         android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
         android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="120dip">
      </ImageView>
      <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textView1" 
        android:text="www.seecycle.com"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20dip">
      </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

code for 2.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"    
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/layout_root">
              <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
              android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
              android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
              />
              <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
              android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
              android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_below="@+id/text"
              android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
              />
              <TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
              android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
              android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
              android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
              />
              <EditText android:id="@+id/text3"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
              android:textColor="#000000"


              />
</LinearLayout>
```

code for .java file

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.1);
setContentView(R.layout.2);//when i use this it generate an error
}
```

Comment: Manage in the same layout fie, use <include> if you want to separate out the files.

Comment: I am totally agree with Sat's answer, if you want to have another layout in the same file then use <include> inside 1st layout, and still if you wants functionality something like visible/hide then make visibility on and off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setContentView` is not meant to be called multiple times. As the name suggests, it "sets" the view, not add it to an existing set of views.

You need to include the 2nd layout xml in the first, using `<include layout="@layout/name-of-layout">`

Update:

Change 1.xml to

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/back_image">
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/loading_logo"
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dip">
    </ImageView>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textView1" 
        android:text="www.seecycle.com"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20dip">
    </TextView>
    <include layout="@layout/2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In the activity, only do

```
setContentView(R.layout.1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need both layouts but wish to keep them separate then creating a 3rd layout file and importing both of the layouts above may be your best option.

e.g.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <include
        layout="@layout/layout1" />
    <include
        layout="@layout/layout2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot call setContentView() twice with different layouts. I think what you are looking for is [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html). This can be used to alternate between two layouts.

[A tutorial I found on google for this](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/26/android-switching-screens-in-an-activity-with-animations-using-viewflipper/)